# What are some considerations to take when programming a .NET framework application to run on a virtual machine (VMWare or Hyper-V)

Tags: .net, virtualization, vmware, virtual-machine, hyper-v

My question is somewhat general. I don't mind a general but practical answer. I am fishing here for something related to how to handle threads and thread synchronization, however, i am interested in the bigger picture of anything related to running a .NET application on a VM.

Should things be coded differently? Do we have to take extra precautions in certain areas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the entire point of virtual machines is that you **don't** have to worry about the fact that you're running on one, unless you literally need hardware access in your programs (which is unlikely for .NET).

The only time you would care is if you needed, say, to query SMART data for a drive, and you needed physical access, in which case you'd have to somehow ask for help from the VM or VMM.

Another example of when you might need hardware-level access is when you're writing a program that's meant to benchmark a device (which, again, is unlikely for .NET), and so you might need the raw power you can get (like how WinSAT doesn't run on a VHD). But these are unlikely scenarios and I doubt you'll run across them.

Comment: Still there are some other things that you could do better, if you knew you are working in a VM... For example SETI-like apps (apps that work in the idle handler, or that wait for the system to be idle)

Comment: what about things like thread synchornization.. Take a look at the volatile keyword in .NET. It seems to be useful when running on some processors but ignored by others. Would a VM cause an issue on that front?

Comment: @Mark: The entire *job* of the VM is to ensure that programs run the same way, so if they don't, it's the VM's problem. Also, it's not that the processors ignore it, it's that their architecture probably already takes care of the memory barriers (which examples are you talking about specifically?). I don't think basic things like that are things you need to worry about, unless you specifically need to communicate with the outside environment.